# Cambiar valor de un elemento de una tabla al hacer click en la casilla correspondiente

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
        <script src="ejercicio3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi. Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque.<br>
        <input type="button" value="+">
        <input type="button" value="-">
 </div>
 <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi. Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque.<br>
        <input type="button" value="+">
        <input type="button" value="-">
 </div>
 <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi. Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque.<br>
        <input type="button" value="+">
        <input type="button" value="-">
 </div>
 <table border="1"><tbody><tr><td >1</td><td >2</td><td >3</td><td >4</td><td >5</td><td >6</td><td >7</td><td >8</td><td >9</td><td >10</td><td >11</td><td >12</td><td >13</td><td >14</td><td >15</td><td >16</td><td >17</td><td >18</td><td >19</td><td >20</td></tr><tr><td >2</td><td >4</td><td >6</td><td >8</td><td >10</td><td >12</td><td >14</td><td >16</td><td >18</td><td >20</td><td >22</td><td >24</td><td >26</td><td >28</td><td >30</td><td >32</td><td >34</td><td >36</td><td >38</td><td >40</td></tr><tr><td >3</td><td >6</td><td >9</td><td >12</td><td >15</td><td >18</td><td >21</td><td >24</td><td >27</td><td >30</td><td >33</td><td >36</td><td >39</td><td >42</td><td >45</td><td >48</td><td >51</td><td >54</td><td >57</td><td >60</td></tr><tr><td >4</td><td >8</td><td >12</td><td >16</td><td >20</td><td >24</td><td >28</td><td >32</td><td >36</td><td >40</td><td >44</td><td >48</td><td >52</td><td >56</td><td >60</td><td >64</td><td >68</td><td >72</td><td >76</td><td >80</td></tr><tr><td >5</td><td >10</td><td >15</td><td >20</td><td >25</td><td >30</td><td >35</td><td >40</td><td >45</td><td >50</td><td >55</td><td >60</td><td >65</td><td >70</td><td >75</td><td >80</td><td >85</td><td >90</td><td >95</td><td >100</td></tr><tr><td >6</td><td >12</td><td >18</td><td >24</td><td >30</td><td >36</td><td >42</td><td >48</td><td >54</td><td >60</td><td >66</td><td >72</td><td >78</td><td >84</td><td >90</td><td >96</td><td >102</td><td >108</td><td >114</td><td >120</td></tr><tr><td >7</td><td >14</td><td >21</td><td >28</td><td >35</td><td >42</td><td >49</td><td >56</td><td >63</td><td >70</td><td >77</td><td >84</td><td >91</td><td >98</td><td >105</td><td >112</td><td >119</td><td >126</td><td >133</td><td >140</td></tr><tr><td >8</td><td >16</td><td >24</td><td >32</td><td >40</td><td >48</td><td >56</td><td >64</td><td >72</td><td >80</td><td >88</td><td >96</td><td >104</td><td >112</td><td >120</td><td >128</td><td >136</td><td >144</td><td >152</td><td >160</td></tr><tr><td >9</td><td >18</td><td >27</td><td >36</td><td >45</td><td >54</td><td >63</td><td >72</td><td >81</td><td >90</td><td >99</td><td >108</td><td >117</td><td >126</td><td >135</td><td >144</td><td >153</td><td >162</td><td >171</td><td >180</td></tr><tr><td >10</td><td >20</td><td >30</td><td >40</td><td >50</td><td >60</td><td >70</td><td >80</td><td >90</td><td >100</td><td >110</td><td >120</td><td >130</td><td >140</td><td >150</td><td >160</td><td >170</td><td >180</td><td >190</td><td >200</td></tr></tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Necesito que el usuario haga click izquierdo y le sume uno al valor del td en cuestión sin que llegue a 200 y, si hace click derecho, le reste uno sin ser negativo.

Comment: Que hiciste? Donde estas teniendo el error? Que camino tomaste? Recuerda que te ayudamos a solucionar errores, no hacemos los ejercicios. Adjunta el `.js` que tienes.

Comment: Simplemente ni siquiera se coger el valor de cada td en donde haya hecho click el usuario. A partir de ahí sabría hacer todo. Y no, no es un ejercicio, es un ejemplo que pongo para trasladarlo a otra cosa (de ahí los td del 1 al 100 tan cutres)

Comment: Tendrías que usar **Javascript** para este tipo de eventos. Investiga un poco sobre los eventos **onclick** y sobre como obtener el contenido **HTML** de un elemento clickeado (más concretamente te diría que investigases como funciona el selector de Javascript **this**). Cualquier duda que te vaya surgiendo en tus intentos puedes notificarla en esta misma pregunta, con una participación activa por tu parte seguro que más de uno se anima a ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creas un evento `click` sobre tu tabla.

`e.srcElement` recoge el elemento seleccionado, una vez lo tengas puedes manipularlo a tu gusto.

```
  document.getElementById("idDeTuTabla").addEventListener("click",function (e) {

            console.log("texto del td: " + e.srcElement.innerHTML);

    } );
```